# Dual Source Blending with Multiple Render Target link error

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am trying to implement text subpixel using dual-source blending.

https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_blend_func_extended.txt

```
layout(location = 0, index = 0) out vec4 fragColor;
layout(location = 0, index = 1) out vec4 srcColor1;

void main()
{
  vec4 scolor0;
  vec4 scolor1;

  // some calulcations

  fragColor = scolor0;
  srcColor1 = scolor1;
}
```

It works fine.
But now I want to write to another render target
like

```
layout(location = 0, index = 0) out vec4 fragColor;
layout(location = 0, index = 1) out vec4 srcColor1;
layout(location = 1) out uvec4 myMRT;
```

and I tried changing location = 1 or location = 2 but in either case,I get this linking error

> error: assembly compile error for fragment shader at offset

> error: too many color outputs when using dual source output

Which is the best way to use MRT in case of Dual source blending?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [OpenGL 4.6 core profile specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf) states in section 17.3.6.3 "Dual Source Blending and Multiple Draw Buffers" (emphasis mine):

> Blend functions that require the second color input
> *(Rs1;Gs1;Bs1;As1)* (`SRC1_- COLOR`, `SRC1_ALPHA`, `ONE_MINUS_SRC1_COLOR`, or `ONE_MINUS_SRC1_ALPHA`)
> **may consume hardware resources that could otherwise be used for rendering to multiple draw buffers. Therefore, the number of draw
> buffers that can be attached to a framebuffer may be lower when using
> dual-source blending.**
>
> **The maximum number of draw buffers that may be attached to a single framebuffer when using dual-source blending functions is
> implementation-dependent and may be queried by calling `GetIntegerv`
> with *pname* `MAX_DUAL_SOURCE_DRAW_BUFFERS`.** When using dual-source
> blending, `MAX_DUAL_SOURCE_DRAW_BUFFERS` should be used in place of
> `MAX_DRAW_BUFFERS` to determine the maximum number of draw buffers
> that may be attached to a single framebuffer. **The value of
> `MAX_DUAL_SOURCE_DRAW_BUFFERS` must be at least 1.**

(The older [`ARB_blend_func_exteded`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_blend_func_extended.txt) extension you referred uses different wording, but also only guarantees a minumum of 1 for `MAX_DUAL_SOURCE_DRAW_BUFFERS`)

So even wit the most current GL spec, GL implementations are not required to support dual-source blending with multiple render targets at all. And looking at the current [report for that capability on gpuinfo.org](https://opengl.gpuinfo.org/displaycapability.php?name=GL_MAX_DUAL_SOURCE_DRAW_BUFFERS) shows that there are **no** real word implementations supporting a value bigger than  1. So nope, you can't do this. At least that's the state of affairs in December 2020.

Comment: In my uber shader, I want to attach MRT under shader option which is a very common workflow but with dual-source blending, it seems impossible and it's actually a blocking issue.